# Yii multi-language not working on a remote server

Tags: internationalization, yii

I setup a site on my local server (Mac OS X 10.7 apache 2, PHP 5.3.8) using elanghandler with standard CPhpMessageSource to handle multi-language. It works fine, but when I port it over to a rented GoDaddy share host (Apache 2, PHP 5.3.6), everything works except the multi-language. The pages would render as if it's working perfectly, but the translation simply didn't kick in. No error messages shown at all. I had the CWebLogRoute turned on and I compared the output from my local server to the GoDaddy server and found them identical. And GoDaddy doesn't have XDebug for me to remote debug. I'm at lost on how to debug.

I can't change the PHP version on GoDaddy share host, and at this point, I'm trying to figure out how to implement multiple PHP versions on my local server to see if the minor difference in PHP version is the cause, but it looks like a pretty big move and would take me a while.

I have log in my config setup like this:

```
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages

            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),

        ),
    ),
```

and in the component section:

```
'ELangHandler' => array(
                  'class'=>'application.extensions.langhandler.ELangHandler',
                    'languages'=>array('en','tw','jp'),
                    'strict'=>false,
                ),
```

I checked the log in the runtime and found no errors…

Does anyone has the slightest idea what it could be or how I should go about this?

If it is of any help, the site now sits on http://test.1226ventures.com. The language switcher is on the top right hand corner.

Comment: Did you configured log module to log errors & warning?   
Also check for errors in protected/runtime/application.log (in case your have file log enabled and it's with different setting from the web log).   
Do you have any lang settings in config file? Like:   
`'sourceLanguage' => 'en_en'`   
How do you set the selected lang in yii?   
`Yii::app()->setLanguage( $language_value_from_request_param );`

Comment: Boris, I've updated my questions to reflect your questions. I looked at the log, but found no related errors. I created routing rules to turn my.domain.com/index.php?lang=xx into my.domain.com/xx/index.php. And the rest is really just the langhandler.

Comment: I have tried this extension, but can't make it work.  
`ELangCUrlManager` is loading, but `ELangHandler` - not. I placed `Yii::log()` and `var_dump()` in `init()` method, but there is no output. No errors/warnings and etc in log at all. Have tried with yii 1.1.8, 1.1.9 and 1.1.10.  
Can you check do the `ELangHandler` loading?

Comment: I think it's loading. If you look at test.1226ventures.com, and you should see the second weblog entry stating "Loading "ELangHandler" application component
in /home/content/41/8934341/html/WebRoot/index.php (13)"

Comment: As you are porting the app from Mac to Linux I guess. you might have to check the case of your translation file names. Linux filesystems threat different cases as different files, while mac does not.